# Python2.7+qt4, utf-8 to gbk or gb18030, garbled

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4.8

```
def respeak(self):
    cText =pyperclip.paste()
    gt = cText.decode('utf-8').encode('gbk')

    self.ui.mainT.setText(QtCore.QString(gt))
```

I am a disabled person in China who has never been to school, so I am not good at English

My problm is.... cText is utf-8,i need turn to GBK or GB18030 to do something,but if cText is chinese word,gt is like this ÊÇ¶à¸öÂÃÐÐÍÆÏúÔ±ÎÊÌâ

So I try this simple one

```
   def respeak(self):
    cText =u'中文'# pyperclip.paste()
    print(cText)
    print repr(cText)
    print(cText.encode('gbk'))
    print repr(cText.encode('gbk'))
```

and I got this

中文

u'\u4e2d\u6587'

����

'\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'

����   <-----What the hell is this?

In the end how to solve it?

I'm using win10 x64 and pycharm and python 2.7 x32

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: That string looks like it has been interpreted as ISO-8859-1 instead of GBK. Maybe your application is running in the wrong locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my *guess* is that the weird symbols is your terminal's attempt at rendering the gbk-formatted bytes as either Unicode or windows ISO encoding. Try `print`ing your string to a file and open it in an editor that understands gbk.